# Writing a Java templating framework - maintaining correct versioning

Tags: java, maven, templates, version-control

I am writing a templating system in Java using Freemarker. I have a data model and template files which access variables in this data model.

I am trying to think of a good way of ensuring that variables mentioned in the template exist in the data model in order for the system to be maintainable. My current thoughts are to implement a versioning system such that both the data model and the templates are coupled together by a version number and changes to the data model will increment the required version number.

Has anyone had experience with this type of thing? What is the simplest way to do this with java? Currently im thinking of using maven and uploading some sort of spec file to our maven repository which will be a dependency with the templates.

Comment: Data model (java classes contributing  the model) and the template files can be included in project module. If you use a version-controller like CVS or subversion you can switch back to previous version and build it properly. I use this approach. If your model and the templates are not in sync you may get build errors(from free marker) or your generated text/software would contain errors which can be caught from the automated tests. Is it helpful?

Comment: Ideally the templates would be under different VCS than the data model. It would be nice to release template changes without having the data model needing to be released even when no changes to the model has been changed. Im thinking now I need better tools to validate the templates with regards to a data model spec instead of a custom solution.